# Testing promises in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise

I'm trying to learn about testing promises in NodeJS, and testing methodologies that I've used in other languages are failing me a bit here. The basic question is **"how do I effectively test indirect inputs and outputs in one or more chained then (and done or catch) promise blocks?"**

Here the source of `lib/test.js`:

```
var Bluebird = require("bluebird"),
    fs = Bluebird.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

function read(file) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(file)
        .then(JSON.parse)
        .done(function () {
            console.log("Read " + file);
        });
}

function main() {
    read("test.json");
}

if (require.main === module) {
    main();
}

module.exports = read;
```

And here's the source of `tests/test.js`

```
var Bluebird = require("bluebird"),
    chai = require("chai"),
    expect = chai.expect,
    sinon = require("sinon"),
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create(),
    proxyquire = require("proxyquire");

chai.use(require("chai-as-promised"));
chai.use(require("sinon-chai"));

describe("test", function () {
    var stub, test;

    beforeEach(function () {
        stub = {
            fs: {
                readFile: sandbox.stub()
            }
        }
        test = proxyquire("../lib/test", stub);
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        sandbox.verifyAndRestore();
    });

    it("reads the file", function () {
        test("test.json");
        expect(stub.fs.readFile).to.have.been.calledWith("test.json");
    });
    it("parses the file as JSON", function () {
        stub.fs.readFileAsync = sandbox.stub().returns(Bluebird.resolve("foo"));
        sandbox.stub(JSON, "parse");
        test("test.json");
        expect(JSON.parse).to.have.been.calledWith("foo");
    });
    it("logs which file was read", function () {
        stub.fs.readFileAsync = sandbox.stub();
        sandbox.stub(JSON, "parse");
        test("bar");
        expect(console.log).to.have.been.calledWith("Read bar")
    });
});
```

I realize that these examples are trivial and contrived, but I'm looking to try and understand how to test promise chains, not how to read a file and parse it as JSON. :)

Also, I'm not tied to any frameworks or anything like that, so if I inadvertently chose poorly when grabbing any of the included NodeJS libraries, a call-out would be appreciated as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that syntax is Mocha, you need to *return* the promises. After all promises work by return value as you return them from methods, so if you don't return them from the tests the test library can't hook on them.

```
describe("testing promises with mocha", () => {
   it("works by returning promises", () => {
      return Promise.resolve("This test passes");
   });
   it("fails by returning promises", () => {
      return Promise.reject(Error("This test fails"));
   });
   it("Lets you chain promises", () => {
      return fs.readFileAsync("test.json").then(JSON.parse);
   });
});
```

(The new function arrow syntax works in NodeJS, if you need to support old node - convert it to `function(){` calls)

Comment: Thank you. I am still using v0.12.2 of NodeJS, so I can't use fat arrows yet.

Answer (score 1):

@Benjamin Gruenbaum

I ended up going with the following in `lib/test.js`:

```
var Bluebird = require("bluebird"),
    fs = Bluebird.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

function read(files) {
    return Bluebird.map(files, function (file) {
        return fs.readFileAsync(file)
            .then(JSON.parse)
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log("Read " + file);
            });
    });
}

function main() {
    read(["test.json", "test2.json"]);
}

if (require.main === module) {
    main();
}

module.exports = read;
```

And this is `tests/test.js`:

```
var Bluebird = require("bluebird"),
    chai = require("chai"),
    chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised"),
    expect = chai.expect,
    sinon = require("sinon"),
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create(),
    proxyquire = require("proxyquire");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.use(require("sinon-chai"));

describe("test", function () {
    var stub, test;

    beforeEach(function () {
        stub = {
            fs: {
                readFile: sandbox.stub()
            }
        };
        sandbox.stub(JSON, "parse");
        test = proxyquire("../lib/test", stub);
        stub.fs.readFileAsync = sandbox.stub().returns(Bluebird.resolve());
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        sandbox.verifyAndRestore();
    });

    it("reads the files", function () {
        var files = ["test.json", "test2.json"];
        return test(files).then(function () {
            var expects = files.map(function (file) {
                return expect(stub.fs.readFileAsync).to.have.been.calledWith(file);
            });
            // expects.push(expect(Bluebird.resolve(1)).to.eventually.equal(2));
            return Bluebird.all(expects);
        });
    });
    it("parses the files as JSON", function () {
        var returns = ["foo", "bar"];
        returns.forEach(function (value, index) {
            stub.fs.readFileAsync.onCall(index).returns(Bluebird.resolve(value));
        });
        return test(["baz", "buz"]).then(function () {
            var expects = returns.map(function (value) {
                return expect(JSON.parse).to.have.been.calledWith(value);
            })
            // expects.push(expect(Bluebird.resolve(1)).to.eventually.equal(2));
            return Bluebird.all(expects);
        });
    });
    it("logs which files were read", function () {
        var files = ["bleep", "blorp"];
        sandbox.spy(console, "log");
        return test(files).then(function () {
            var expects = files.map(function (file) {
                return expect(console.log).to.have.been.calledWith("Read " + file);
            });
            // expects.push(expect(Bluebird.resolve(1)).to.eventually.equal(2));
            return Bluebird.all(expects);
        });
    });
});
```

I left the commented-out 1 === 2 assertions there to ensure I wasn't getting false positives (like when a `.then` wouldn't get called because I was doing it wrong).

Comment: This looks like a perfectly fine solution. Cheers.